# Syntax error in php file and unknown error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a `stock item` from my database but I keep getting this error and I can't fathom how to fix it. Any ideas?

This is the error:

> "The details deleted are as follows: 
>   Notice: Undefined index: itemdescription in /var/www/vhosts/c2agolf.candept.com/httpdocs/Conor/test/delete/delete.php on line 17 Item Description : 
>   There was an error in the SQL Query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''delete' = 1 WHERE itemdescription = 'Array [itemdescription]'' at line 1"

Here's my code:

```
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "deletestock.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "content">
<div class = "transBox">
<input type = "button" id = "MenuBtn" value = "Menu" onClick = "window.location = 'c2agolf.candept.com/menu.html';">

<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$sql = "UPDATE Stock SET 'delete' = 1 WHERE itemdescription = '$_POST [itemdescription]' ";

echo "The details deleted are as follows: <br>";
echo  "<label><b>Item Description : </b> " . $_POST['itemdescription'] . "<br></label>";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
    {
        die("There was an error in the SQL Query: " . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "<script> alert('The stock has been deleted'); </script>";
    mysql_close($conn);
?>

<form action = "delete.html.php" method = "POST">
<br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Return to Insert Page">

</form>
```

Comment: I suggest you learn mysqli or PDO instead of mysql as mysql is outdated and will soon be deprecated

Comment: To start, remove the space in: `$_POST [itemdescription]` to get `$_POST[itemdescription]`

Comment: Hint: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Plus, where is your form element bearing the name attribute for `itemdescription`? This makes it all that much more harder to give you a concrete/definite answer/solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space between `$_POST` and `[itemdescription]`...  and "delete" is a keyword and should be escaped using backticks if it's being used as a column name...

Try changing:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Stock SET 'delete' = 1 WHERE itemdescription = '$_POST [itemdescription]' ";
```

to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Stock SET `delete` = 1 WHERE itemdescription = '" . $_POST['itemdescription'] . "' ";
```

or:

```
$itemdescription = $_POST['itemdescription'];
$sql = "UPDATE Stock SET `delete` = 1 WHERE itemdescription = '$itemdescription' ";
```

Comment: Good catch, I did indeed miss that the 'delete' should be backticked rather than single quoted if in fact the field is named "delete", which is a keyword...

Comment: You get to know what those reserved words are after a while ;-) Plus, the syntax error is obvious.

Comment: Yup, I did the "assume" thing and assumed they were backticks, and we know where "assuming" can lead LOL

Comment: The OP as do others, may have been watching tutorials from a video, and the ticks resemble quotes so they mistake them as such. That is a mistake that is often made.